# Creating intents using Dialogflow v2 api in Python

Tags: python, dialogflow-es

I'm trying to create intents in my Dialogflow agent using the python v2 library. I'm new to this and the python documentation isn't helping me much. This is the code I have so far, which gives me "TypeError: create_intent() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given"

```
import os
from google.cloud import dialogflow_v2

os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]=r"C:\\path\\to\\credentials.json"

intents_client = dialogflow_v2.IntentsClient()
project = "my_project"
parent = intents_client.common_project_path(project)
intent = dialogflow_v2.types.Intent(
    display_name = "Renate's new Intent"
)
response = intents_client.create_intent(parent, intent)
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the `create_intent` with keyword/named argument instead? Such as `create_intent(parent-parent, intent=intent)`.

Comment: Thanks I think that worked, although I'm getting a different error now: 400 Resource name 'projects/my-project' does not match 'projects/*/locations/*/agent'

Comment: You need project_agent_path instead of common_project_path.

Comment: No, project_agent_path is what I had before but it seems to be deprecated.

Comment: I ended up using a hardcoded project path